# Hornetq large messages filling up disk space

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, hornetq

I have configured hornetq for handling large messages but large message directory becomes too large if client is not up ,consuming whole disk space

Plz help to figure out how to delete or clean large message folder after message been delivered ?

also paging directory not being created in jboss/server/default/data/hornetq.

Comment: Please give more details.

Answer (score 3):

The messages should be removed after consumed.

If they are filling up it means your clients are not acking the messages.

What version are you using? I would also update the versions as we have fixed a few bugs around large message deliver.

Comment: I have a similar bug, I'm using JBoss 6.1 GA, with the default hornetQ version, that is 2.2.5.Final. the <JBOSS>\server\default\data\hornetq\largemessages grows in time.
The client is in the same ear of the sender.

Comment: is there a parameter to auto clear the non ack messages?

Answer (score 1):

Stop the instance and clear all the messaginglargemessages and messagingjournal then start the instance again.